# omitting alphabet while ordering by

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query:

```
 select U.IdUser,U.memberID,SL.Title from users U
                   inner join statuslist SL on
                   U.idStatus=SL.IdStatus
                   where U.idOrg='1'and isnull(U.memberID,'')!=''
                   order by   U.memberID
```

It gives me result:

[image]

Here i want to have B12 MemberID to come before B110 (means 12 comes before 110 thats why).

How can i acheive it??

I tried below...

```
select U.IdUser,U.memberID,SL.Title from users U
                   inner join statuslist SL on
                   U.idStatus=SL.IdStatus
                   where U.idOrg='1'and isnull(U.memberID,'')!=''
                   order by     Substring(U.memberID,2,LEN(U.memberID))
```

But not giving correct results.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of difference between `order by with strings` and `order by with numbers`:

```
select U.IdUser,U.memberID,SL.Title from users U
               inner join statuslist SL on
               U.idStatus=SL.IdStatus
               where U.idOrg='1'and isnull(U.memberID,'')!=''
               order by     CAST(Substring(U.memberID,2,LEN(U.memberID)-1) AS INT);

select U.IdUser,U.memberID,SL.Title from users U
               inner join statuslist SL on
               U.idStatus=SL.IdStatus
               where U.idOrg='1'and isnull(U.memberID,'')!=''
               order by     CONVERT(INT,Substring(U.memberID,2,LEN(U.memberID)-1));
```

Comment: Should `LEN(U.memberID)` be `LEN(U.memberID)-1` instead?